# QTP and DotNetFactory with Events

Tags: vb.net, vb6, qtp

I am using the below code  to create a UI on QTP

```
Set objTree = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Windows.Forms.TreeView", "System.Windows.Forms")
Set objDataGridView = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView", "System.Windows.Forms")
```

I have several questions on this

1. Is the above code using VBScript, VB6 or VB.NET ?
2. How do I add event to my `objTree` ? I'd like to put a listener to it and when it is clicked, I will trigger a function that will populate the `objDataGridView`

Comment: Are you using a third-party tool with the `DotNetFactory` class? Or did you just find this code online somewhere?

Comment: I dont use any thirdparty tools. This code is used to draw a UI on my QTP test.

Comment: QTP is a third-party tool.

Comment: Is is VBScript - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional

Comment: so is there anyway I can achieve it with QTP ?

Comment: I assume so, but I haven't done and VBScript in years and I've never used QTP. I would Google this if I were you.

Comment: QTP is used to test applications. Why are you drawing a UI in your QTP test?

Comment: I need to create a UI which is similar to QTP ALM / QC. Do I need to use VB.Net ?

Comment: I'd say -- yes, for more reasons than I'd want to type in into a comment.